# Graphite doesnt show unit for time metrics

Tags: metrics, graphite, micrometer, spring-micrometer

Graphite doesn't show the unit for time metrics. I am not sure if it is milliseconds or microseconds. How to verify that? I am reporting from JMX MeterRegistry.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the "spring-micrometer" tag you added, I assume you're using Micrometer.

Base time unit is governed by [`MeterRegistry.getBaseTimeUnit()`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/MeterRegistry.java#L206).
`GraphiteMeterRegistry` doesn't override it and [extends `DropwizardMeterRegistry`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/implementations/micrometer-registry-graphite/src/main/java/io/micrometer/graphite/GraphiteMeterRegistry.java#L29), so [`DropwizardMeterRegistry.getBaseTimeUnit()`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/dropwizard/DropwizardMeterRegistry.java#L124) will be used. As you can see, it's milliseconds.

UPDATE:

When reporting to the Graphite, there are [time unit conversions](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/implementations/micrometer-registry-graphite/src/main/java/io/micrometer/graphite/GraphiteMeterRegistry.java#L75-L76). [Time unit for rates is seconds and time unit for durations is milliseconds by default](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/implementations/micrometer-registry-graphite/src/main/java/io/micrometer/graphite/GraphiteConfig.java#L58-L65).

Comment: Yes, you are right! I am using Micrometer. Thanks for guiding me to the source code. I have a better clarity now. I wish graphite had units on it's y axis. :/

Comment: I am using JMXMeterRegistry and not GraphiteMeterRegistry.

Comment: @hegde Is there any reason not to use `GraphiteMeterRegistry` for Graphite?

Comment: I am implementing micrometer in spring and exporting metrics to jmx(jconsole) which is then read by graphite. This is because someone else is taking care of the graphite and they are reading from the jmx metrics. :/

Answer (score 0):

you can add unit to your Y -axis from general settings in graphite. For that you need  to confirm your unit from code,the way you are publishing to JMX MeterRegistry.